# Spring Boot not able to read properties inside profiles expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Env Details:

- Spring Boot 2.1.15.RELEASE
- Spring 5.2.2.RELEASE

I have application.yml file as below,

```
creds:
    first: default value
    
---

spring.profiles: dev

creds:
    first: dev value


---

spring.profiles: dev & mobile

creds:
    first: dev-mobile value
```

and

spring.profiles.active=dev,mobile

However, the problem is that it always loads 'default value'.

Property under profile 'dev & mobile' is never loaded.

Appreciate any help.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml

Comment: You are using yml format, its not spring.profiles, its spring: profiles:

Comment: @DineshDontha - tried that too, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is no way that your **application.properties** will pick the combined profile (**profile**: dev & mobile) *if you define profiles individually(**profile**: dev) & also combining it with other profile again(combined with mobile again, I mean **dev & mobile**)*. This does not give you any Exceptions, but your combined profile will not get a pick.

The documentation says that, we can combine profiles with symbols &  | and other symbols [please refer docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml), we can make such any complex combinations. But, I don't recommend you define a profile individually & also combine it with other profiles, like you combined **dev & mobile**, after define **dev** profile separately.

Following example shows, how it works?

**application.yaml**

```
creds:
  first: default value

---

spring:
  profiles: dev

creds:
  first: dev value

---

spring:
  profiles: mobile

creds:
  first: mobile val

---

spring:
  profiles: dev & mobile

creds:
  first: dev-mobile value
```

**What happens, if we define a profile individually & combining it with other profile?** (like you did).

In this application.yml file, I have defined dev, mobile & combined profile(dev & mobile), and as we know there is also a default profile.

If I don't invoke any profile, as we know, it will pick default profile. For Example, if we are reading a property like this:

```
@Value("${creds.first}")
String value;
```

**property value**: default value

If **--spring.profiles.active=dev** , then it will pick **dev** profile.

**property value**: dev value

If -**-spring.profiles.active=mobile** , then it will pick **mobile** profile.

**property value**: mobile val

If **--spring.profiles.active=mobile,dev** , then here, we have trying to invoke both profiles at same time, ideally, we expect the combined profile should be picked. But it will be not picked. Because, we have defined separate profiles(**profile: dev** and **profile: mobile** separately), firstly, it will read the property from **mobile** profile and then it reads the property from **dev** profile, if found, then it overrides with property value from **dev** profile. If not found, it will stick to property value of **mobile** profile only. I mean to say, it reads

**property value**: dev value

If **--spring.profiles.active=dev,mobile**, then here, it first reads the property value from **dev** profile, then, the again it looks for the property in **mobile** profile, if found, overrides the value. If not found, it will stick to property value of **dev** profile only.

That's why it will not read the combined profile (dev & mobile).

**How & when it reads combined profile?**

As per documentation, it can pick a combined profile, if the mentioned profiles should not have been defined separately elsewhere:

Example: application.yaml

```
creds:
  first: default value

---

spring:
  profiles: showcase

creds:
  first: showcase value

---

spring:
  profiles: dev & mobile

creds:
  first: dev-mobile value
```

here, dev, mobile are combined using & and they are not separately defined elsewhere.
So, now if we invoke **--spring.profiles.active=dev,mobile**, it will pick the combined profile value

**property value**: dev-mobile value

Lastly, if **--spring.profiles.active=dev** or **--spring.profiles.active=mobile**, it will not pick the combined profile. So, it will sick to default profile.

**property value**: default value

Sample: https://github.com/donthadineshkumar/multi-profile-document.git

Comment: This is a good explanation, Thanks. However, I feel the documentation lacks this information. 
I tried the approach and found the same behavior. Raising the issue with spring team, I have seen some examples where people are using in a way I have provided but not sure if it is as per their expectations.

Comment: I tested & provided example. I don't know what your missing. Anyways goodluck

Comment: I just had a different understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you added every environments in same file
it should be
one file for dev
application-dev.yml

```
reds:
    first: dev value
```

another file for production

application-production.yml

```
reds:
    first: production value
```

goes on.

Comment: The documentation says, it can be added in one file,
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml